# How to decipher the transaction message in innodb status log.

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have several transactions that seem have stalled. Looking at the innodb status log, I found several messages similar to the following:

---TRANSACTION 69DBBB, ACTIVE 947 sec starting index read, thread declared inside InnoDB 373
mysql tables in use 4, locked 0
MySQL thread id 820, OS thread handle 0x7ef64c454700, query id 625198....

***Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 69DBBC, sees < 6699C2***

I need help understanding exactly what it means.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is truncated when there are many running transactions. The size depends on your version. See "Standard InnoDB Monitor output is limited..." for your version on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-monitors.html